# calling private variable with abstract method overriding

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, abstract, super

I have an assignment where I need to create an abstract class containing constructer and an abstract method that will be overrriden by the subclass.

The object of the assignment is to determine the areas of different polygons while having the RegularPolygon class be the base class.

When I call the method by the subclass extension it prints out zero. I know the problem is the the scope of the variable. Basically I know that my variable side isn't being read from the super class because its private. I don't know how to fix that without changing it from private to public or protected. It needs to stay private.

RegularPolygon

```
public abstract class RegularPolygon
{
    private double side;

    public RegularPolygon(double length)
    {
        side = length;
    }

    public abstract double getArea();
}
```

Square

```
public class Square extends RegularPolygon
{
    private double side;

    public Square(double length)
    {
        super(length);
    }

    public double getArea()
    {
        return side*side; //this returns 0
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to create a public `getSide()` method for `RegularPolygon` to retrieve the value in `side`. This way you will only be able to retrieve the value in `side` and still not be able to change it.

Here's how the code would be:

```
// Main.java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Square sq = new Square(3);
    System.out.println(sq.getArea()); // 9.0
}
```

This would be the RegularPolygon class

```
public abstract class RegularPolygon
{
    private double side;

    public RegularPolygon(double length)
    {
        side = length;
    }

    public abstract double getArea();

    // Add this...
    public double getSide() {
        return side;
    }
}
```

And... the Square class

```
public class Square extends RegularPolygon{
    public Square(double length)
    {
        super(length);
    }
    public double getArea()
    {
        // use 'this.getSide()' to retrieve the value in 'side'
        return this.getSide()*this.getSide();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `private` fields in a given class in extensions of that class. Thus the `side` you're accessing in your `getArea()` is the `side` in `Square`, which is never initialized.

The best practice answer to this is to create a public getter for `side` so that subclasses can access it (though not edit it).

```
public abstract class RegularPolygon {
    private double side;

    public RegularPolygon(double length) {
        side = length;
    }

    public double getSideLength() {
        return side;
    }

    public abstract double getArea();
}



public class Square extends RegularPolygon {
    public Square(double length) {
        super(length);
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return getSideLength()*getSideLength();
    }    
}
```

If you specifically want subclasses to be able to directly access the `side` field, make it `protected` instead of `private`.